# Does MVC 3 Preview 1 run on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio-2010, asp.net, mvc

I know, I have an older development box and I should really upgrade to a new machine with Windows 7.  But that costs money that I don't have, so I'm still building on a PC running Windows XP (SP3).

Now that the new version of ASP.NET's MVC is in preview, I was really excited to play with it in Visual Studio.  Unfortunately, [Microsoft claims](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=cb42f741-8fb1-4f43-a5fa-812096f8d1e8) (I haven't yet verified) that it only works with Windows Vista or newer.

Does anyone think it will work on Windows XP anyway?  I am running Visual Studio 2010, so I see no reason why I shouldn't be able to install it right on top ... but I'm wary of installation notes and wanted to poll the community first ...

Comment: Well VS2010 and .NET 4 install OK on XP, so I'm hoping that it'll work.

Comment: I've noticed that, and I love using VS2010 on my XP system ... I'm just concerned that Microsoft glossed over the system requirements for MVC 3.  They list out the various Windows Server editions as well as Vista and Windows 7 ... but XP is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC3 Release Candidate installs and works *fine* on Windows XP SP3, based on my personal quick test. There might be disappointments waiting around the corner but the MVC3-based simple solution builds and runs in Internet Explorer.

I too was very nervous about not finding Windows XP in the list of system requirements for MVC3 Release Candidate. I hope it was helpful.